# Prepare data : many products per row

Tags: data, data-formats

I would like to find how to change my data structure to make it compatible with a ML model, with the following constraints :

- A Product is defined by {id, price, continuousVariable1, ..., continuousVariable10}
- The training set is train.csv. Each line contains a date, **a Product, and a list of Products** (competing products)
- For each row of train.csv, the size of the list of Products may change.

It would be easy if I had only one competing products : I could put all columns in the same file. But I have many competing products.
The output variable is the product price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I my opinion, the best way is if you  create a column for every(!) product. Yes, u will  get a high dimensional sparse Matrix but it should solve you problem quickly.